# Finding xml element value case insensitive using XmlSlurper/GPath?

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

I am parsing a piece of XML using XmlSlurper and need to find an xml elements value.
The challenge in this is that i am not always sure if the casing in the xml document will be correct, so i need to find the element in any possible way.

Example:

```
<start>
   <Header>
      <Elem>1234</Elem>
   </Header>
</start>
```

Getting the value of **Elem** will be:

```
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
parsedXml.Header.Elem
```

but i also need to find it when the casing is different.. so is there a  way in which i can express to find the value of Elem when the casing is different?

```
<start>
   <header>
      <elem>1234</elem>
   </header>
</start>

def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
parsedXml.header.elem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There probably is a much better solution (e.g. it seems that using XPath it should be possible to [compare node names case insensitively](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-460915.html)), but converting the document to lowercase will work. If you care about the casing of the text nodes inside the document, you may only convert to lowercase the tag elements:

```
def toLowerCaseXmlTags(xmlText) {
    xmlText.replaceAll(/<[^<>]+>/) { it.toLowerCase() }
}

text = """
<start>
   <Header>
      <Elem>1234</Elem>
      <SomeText>This should PRESERVE casing</SomeText>
   </Header>
</start>
"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(toLowerCaseXmlTags(text))
assert xml.header.elem.text() == '1234'
assert xml.header.sometext.text() == 'This should PRESERVE casing'
```

Quick and dirty, but it works :P

Answer (score 2):

XML is case sensitive and so is the property lookup of XmlSlurper results.  You will need to use the [`GPathResult.find()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#find%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) method:

```
def header = parsedXml.find { it.name().toLowerCase() == 'header' }
def elem = header.find { it.name().toLowerCase() == 'elem' }
```

Check out the [groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) for more ways you can use XmlSlurped documents.

Comment: You can also do `it.name().equalsIgnoreCase('header')` to do a case-insensitive comparison directly =D